# Receiving "Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11" on HTML5 websocket when calling .send(data) using Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am currently trying to develop a small chat application using node.js. This is my first node project but I am getting an error and I'm not really sure how to solve it.

I have written a simple chat server in node which is below.

```
var port = 3000;
var net = require('net');
var clients = [];

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  clients.push(socket);
  bindEventHandlers(socket);
});

setInterval(function(){
  console.log(clients.length);
}, 2000);

server.listen(port);
console.log('Server is listening on localhost:' + port);

function bindEventHandlers(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    broadcastDataToAllClient(data, socket);
  });
  socket.on('close', function(){
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
  });
  socket.on('error', function(){
    console.log('Known Error << "It\'s a feature!"');
  })
}

function broadcastDataToAllClient(data, socket) {
  for (var client in clients) {
      if(clients[client] == socket){ continue; }
      clients[client].write(data);
  }
}
```

And a quick client interface

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Node.js Chat Server</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init(){
                if (window.WebSocket) {
                    var input = document.getElementById('messageBox');
                    var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/");
                    input.onkeyup = function(e){
                        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                            console.log('sending message');
                            webSocket.send('some data');
                        }
                    };
                    webSocket.onopen = function(e){
                        alert('Open');
                    }
                    webSocket.onmessage = function(e){
                        console.log('Message');
                    }
                    webSocket.onclose = function(e){
                        console.log('Close');
                    }
                    webSocket.onerror = function(e){
                        console.log('Error');
                    }   
                } else {
                    console.log('unable to support :(');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body lang="en" onload="init();">
        <h1>Node.js Chat Server</h1>
        <h3>Welcome to this simple chat server!</h3>
        <input id="messageBox" size="50" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When I call the `webSocket.send('some data')` I receive this error `Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11`. In the chat-server code I have a loop which logs the number of current clients so I know that the browser is connected.

Not sure where to go from here and any help would be much appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 7):

When you do `webSocket.send('some data')` the socket connection must be established, or specifically  socket.readyState == 1.

You can check the websocket events [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm). To make sure this never happens, you should send after connection open, by using `Socket.onopen` event handler. You can do it like this.

```
if(webSocket.readyState == 1){
    webSocket.send('some data');
  }
else{
    webSocket.onopen = function(e){
        webSocket.send('some data');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks for the tip. I'm afraid that it didn't work. I confirmed this by calling the .send() in the chrome console and it produced the same error.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's got rid of the error but it still isn't sending the message. I am now thinking that it hasn't got a 'complete connection' from the server (if you know what I mean) hence why its not sending the message.

Comment: @alexjfno1, sorry for overlooking it but `net` module is for TCP sockets not websockets. So that is why you are not able to connect to the node server. You have to use something like socket.io. Check https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#web-sockets--ajax for more modules

Comment: OK that makes sense, Thanks for all your help and advice. Thanks for the link and I will take a look and try and get something working.